# How to take fields value from another table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table field in which I want to calculate the price of an order. In that table I have a field where you choose what dishes did the client order. And I need to get the prices of those exact dishes from another table and then sum them up. I want to calculate in field SASK and take prices from table VALGIARASTIS. So what should the formula be?

For example in field dish I choose Balandeliai,Bulviniai blynai, Cepelinai formula should take those names and get prices of it from table VALGIARASTIS and sum them up.

Here's a screenshot for you to understand.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any VBA to process the form's multi-select field?  If so, please post that.  It will help others to provide specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will not be a formula.  It will be a VBA function that receive an array from the multi-value combo box, uses it to build a filter for the data in the `VALGIARASTIS` table, and uses an aggregate query to `SUM()` the price values.

For the first part, you can refer to these links:

- http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135546

Once you have the means to filter a recordset, you can run an SQL query on the results using the `SUM()` function to get your total.  You can run a DAO cursor through the recordset and get your total that way, but SQL is better.

Comment: I still didn't find the solution. I was trying to google "Checkbox array sum" - no useful results... Maybe you can help me now? Because I must finish this database on saturday. :/